# undefined error for callback function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

I'm trying to perform some actions by using jquery `diferred` in my script. But when I execute the script it produces the error `TypeError: func(...) is undefined`. But the function is already defined and it also accepting the calls.

Here is My script:

```
        verify: function(func, $this, verPass) {
            console.log('In verify');
            var data = {};
            data.url = 'service/verifier.php';
            data.data = {pass: verPass};
            data.async = true;
            this.fetch(data).always(function() {
                var result=true;
                if (result) {
                    console.log(func);
                    func().then(function(){         //Here I'm getting error( Fiddle Line No:149)
                        $('#loader').children('.infoCont').empty().append($('<span/>').css({'color': '#000', 'background': '#35cc83', 'display': 'inline-block', 'margin': '0 0 0 -115px', 'padding': '0 25px 7px'}).html('<h2>Profile Updated Successfully</h2>'));
                    console.log('success');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");
                        $this.closest('.modal').modal('hide');
                    }, 2000);
                    },
                    function(){
                        console.log('Failed');
                        $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");
                    $this.closest('form').find('.warning-mes').empty().append($('<span/>').css({'color': '#000', 'background': '#FFEBE8'}).html('Failed to complete the action. Please Try again...'));
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");
                    $this.closest('form').find('.warning-mes').empty().append($('<span/>').css({'color': '#000', 'background': '#FFEBE8'}).html('Incorrect password'));
                }
            });
        }
```

And I have created two fiddles. One is with original script and another is with dummy. But the dummy script works as expected. I'm not able to figure out what mistake I have made in my original script.

[Original Script Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesPJ/nU2NL/)

[Dummy Script Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesPJ/NXK7W/10/)

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: also mention when issue appears in your question!

Comment: In the original fiddle you [didn't select the options in the menu](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/nU2NL/4/). It looks like it works.

Comment: @C-link When I submit password issue appears

Comment: @Andy What you mean...

Comment: `TypeError : Object [object Object] has no method 'model'` - $target.modal

Comment: @RobSedgwick I don't Understand what you are saying

Comment: Neither do I ( I just ran your script, did you write it ? ) and that is what it errors on.

Comment: @RobSedgwick I'm not getting that error....